# How to check if string have two or more identic characters next to each other?

Tags: regex

I must reject string that have, for example:

```
abcddef
Aduuuop
```

but strings:

```
AaAaAa
abcDdef
```

are valid. How to make the correct regex for this?

Comment: I'm confused and I don't know if I just can't catch up with the question :(

Comment: Please explain the pattern in these strings.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to edit a question and add the answer. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by posting an answer in the space below provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use back references.
Try this regex: `([A-Za-z])\1+`

`([A-Za-z])` will match all alphabets (upper or lower case).
`\1` is a back reference to the first captured group i.e. `([A-Za-z])`.
`+` looks for one or more repetitions.

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/eR1tO9/1).

Comment: You have just guessed at what he is asking without any kind of confirmation, so this is a terrible answer as it might not even be what he is asking for.

Comment: It's pretty clear to me from the title and the explanation. Good for you that you asked for a confirmation but I think the OP is asking for a regex that matches strings which have same characters placed successively. Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: You are correct, I did not pay close enough attention to the title.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the following:

```
^((.)(?!\2))+$
```

This should work.

Btw: I can´t understand where the problem with this answer is...... Yeah maybe it´s a basics-question, but for me it´s clear what he/she wants to know and wehre the problem is.